# Why the functions doesn't return new line with replaceable keywords?

Tags: arrays, c, string, character

Hey just doing some exercises in c, one is saying to  **replace tabs in the input string with any other characters** , i restrict myself to only using `getchar()`, no `gets() fgets()` etc..., as my learning book didn't catch it yet, so i tried to not break the flow, the code below just `printf()` the same line it receives, can you please examine why ?

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main(){

        char line[20];
        char c;
        int i = 0;
        printf("Enter name: ");
        while ( c != '\n'){
                c = getchar();
                line[i] = c;
                ++i;}
        while (line[i] != '\0')
                if (line[i] == '\t')
                        line[i] = '*';

        printf("Line is %s \n", line);

        return 0;}
```

Comment: Your second `while` loop doesn't do anything with `i` - it just uses whatever value the previous `while` loop set it to last.

Comment: The second `while` loop is reading array elements that have not been initialised or written to, and `i` may not even be within the array bounds.

Comment: You must also write the NUL termninator the second loop is looking for.

Comment: Note that [`gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/15168) so you should not bother to learn it (only learn that you should _never_ use it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `c`, which is used in `c != '\n'`, is not initialized at first. Its initial value is indeterminate and using is value without initializng invokes *undefined behavior*.
- You are checking `line[i] != '\0'`, but you never assigned `'\0'`  to `line` unless `'\0'` is read from the stream.
- You should initialize `i` before the second loop and update `i` during the second loop.
- Return values of `getchar()` should be assigned to `int` to distinguish between `EOF` and an valid character.
- You should perform index check not to cause buffer overrun.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 20

int main(){

        char line[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int c = 0;
        int i = 0;
        printf("Enter name: ");
        while ( i + 1 < BUFFER_SIZE && c != '\n'){
                c = getchar();
                if (c == EOF) break;
                line[i] = c;
                ++i;
        }
        line[i] = '\0';
        i = 0;
        while (line[i] != '\0'){
                if (line[i] == '\t')
                        line[i] = '*';
                ++i;
        }

        printf("Line is %s \n", line);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey @MikeCAT thanks for the valuable explanations , i literately wrote it in my notebook , i still have 2 questions though: 1) why ```i+1<BUFFER_SIZE``` what's the matter with ```i+1``` , and 2) why do we need to add a ```\0```to line string, i read somewhere that the compiler  add an automatic ```\0``` to  string data type?

Comment: the lessons were amazing but your code still give the same input line indeed.

Comment: @RidaEN-Nasry [This code works for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BGDuUhs4PAV8JoQN).

Comment: @RidaEN-Nasry 1) `i+1<BUFFER_SIZE` is checking if it is safe to execute `line[i] = '\0';` (after the loop) after incrementing `i` in the loop body. `i+1` is the value of `i` after the increment. 2) You are not reading strings via API but reading characters and manually constructing a string here, so no terminator (`'\0'`) is added automatically and you need to add it manually.

Comment: thanks a lot @MikeCAT  one last question, when we assigned ```line[i] = '\0' ```, supposedly it was added as the last element to ```line[i]```? how's that ? i mean do array[i] or the i-th element of any array always refer to the last one?

Comment: @RidaEN-Nasry `line[i] = '\0'` is assigning `'\0'` as the last character of the string because `i` is updated before that to make `line[i]` represent one element after the last assigned element. Generally `array[i]` is just an i-th element of `array` and there are no guarantee that it is the last element.